# Python-pptx: update or change existing chart data

Tags: python-pptx

I open a pptx file and want to change the chart dataset. How can I do that?

```
prs = Presentation("mypresentation.pptx")
chart = prs.slides[0].shapes[2].chart
```

I get the chart as above from the slide. I don't want to change the style or any thing of the chart. Want to keep as it is. Just want to change the dataset values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

The data providing the values displayed in a PowerPoint chart can be changed with `python-pptx` using the `Chart.replace_data()` method.
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#pptx.chart.chart.Chart.replace_data

A new `ChartData` object is created to hold the new data, then that object is passed to the `.replace_data()` method:

```
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData

# ---define new chart data---
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))

# ---replace chart data---
chart.replace_data(chart_data)
```

Note that this procedure is slightly different for an XY/Scatter chart or Bubble chart because those chart types use a different chart-data object.

Comment: Nice but how do we edit the axis titles of a chart which is already present in my ppt file from an embedded excel sheet? you can find more info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949464/python-ppt-find-and-replace-within-a-chart

Answer (score 0):

To add to scanny's answer, if you want to replace data for  XY/Scatter do the following:

1. Instead of `CategoryChartData` you have to use `XySeriesData` and `XyChartData`
2. You need to add your data as a x,y (XySeriesData) using `XyChartData.add_series()` , best approach to do so is by adding each pair individually following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62108452/15523646
3. If you have more than one series, you can loop through them, and repeat step 2 for each series.
4. Finally replacing the data is the same as in scanny's answer.