# xy scatter plot with python-pptx not working

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to make a simple python-pptx xy scatter chart with x and y series data but unsuccessful so far.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches,Pt

from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.chart.data import XySeriesData

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]

slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
slide2 = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"
chart_data = XySeriesData
chart_data.x_values=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
chart_data.y_values=[10,22,33,38,40,43]
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(2), Inches(8), Inches(3)
chart = slide2.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.XY_SCATTER, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data).chart

prs.save('test1.pptx')
```

The error i get is

File "C:\Users\adnan\Google Drive\Learning\Python\5g_tti_parser\untitled0.py", line 31, in 
    chart = slide2.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.XY_SCATTER, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data).chart

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\shapes\shapetree.py", line 250, in add_chart
    rId = self.part.add_chart_part(chart_type, chart_data)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\parts\slide.py", line 174, in add_chart_part
    chart_part = ChartPart.new(chart_type, chart_data, self.package)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\parts\chart.py", line 30, in new
    chart_blob = chart_data.xml_bytes(chart_type)

AttributeError: type object 'XySeriesData' has no attribute 'xml_bytes'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am working on this as well today - it looks like you skipped some steps.

Make sure you have the right imports, which include:

```
from pptx.chart.data import XySeriesData, XyChartData
```

Change this line:

```
chart_data = XySeriesData
```

to instantiate the class XyChartData:

```
chart_data = XyChartData()
```

then you need to add a series (which creates the XySeries object), give it a name and a number format (I am using None)

```
chart_data.add_series('name_of_series', number_format= None)
```

THEN

```
chart_data.x_values=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
chart_data.y_values=[10,22,33,38,40,43]
```

I'm not fully sure if this will solve your problem, but I hope it helps. I was able to replace the data in a scatterplot this way today.

EDIT:

Setting the x_values and y_values on the chart_data object has been inconsistent and unreliable. In example below, set your numeric lists to variable names. I am using x_values_list and y_values_list for clarity.

New method:

Save your add_series object to a variable, and add x & y data points individually.

```
chart_data = XyChartData()    
cd = chart_data.add_series('name_of_series', number_format= None)
    for x, y in list(zip(x_values_list, y_values_list)):
         cd.add_data_point(x, y, number_format=None)
```

At this point, chart_data contains your series object and can be inserted into the chart shape, while cd represents the XySeries object. I think x_values and y_values are meant as accessors more than writers, perhaps? I could not set those values at the XySeries level successfully. I had many issues trying to set my lists to those attributes at the XyChartData level as well. This is functioning much better.

Comment: yes you are right, your New Method is more reliable

Comment: Now i am stuck with setting with font sizes on axis titles, axis values and chart titles :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122018/how-to-set-font-size-of-chart-axis-values-and-axis-titles-in-python-pptx-for-xys